# (asp.net) Gridview dynamical columns put margin on one of them

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

Been trying to style my gridview for some time. It gets data dynamical and would then able to put margin (padding) on one of the columns. 
Is this even possibly to do? 
Because when I try to get the columns count it allways return 0. 
Is there some other way to make this?

Also would like to cellSpace but only Horizontal not vertical any suggestions there?

```
 gwResult.DataSource = dvData
    gwResult.DataBind()
    gwResult.GridLines = GridLines.None



    'Dim desc As Integer
    'gwResult.RowStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left


    'headCell = gwResult.HeaderRow.Cells.Count
    'rows = gwResult.Rows.Count

    'For i As Integer = 0 To headCell - 1
    '    gwResult.HeaderRow.Cells(i).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
    '    headerText = gwResult.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text

    '    If headerText = "Description" Then
    '        desc = i
    '        'Else
    '        '    gwResult.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Width = 75
    '    End If
    '  Next

    'For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.gwResult.Rows
    '    'row.Cells(desc).CssClass = "gwStyle"
    '    For i As Integer = 0 To headCell - 1
    '        If IsNumeric(row.Cells(i).Text) Then
    '            row.Cells(i).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
    '        End If
    '    Next
    'Next
```

Comment: Why you are not making this thing inside RowDataBound event of the GridView

Comment: Sorry I´m new to VB coding so what is RowDataBound, can you give me a example?

Comment: you are to new to vb or new to gridview coding???

Comment: Gridview coding never done that before.